# "yield outside of block" while trying to use activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter

Tags: mysql, activerecord, jruby

this happens when i deploy my app to glassfish as a war:

```
    [#|2011-06-24T17:11:40.903-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=135;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Fri Jun 24 17:11:40 -0500 2011
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  yield called out of block
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.2/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:91:in `tap'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.2/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:91:in `initialize'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.2/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31:in `new'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.2/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31:in `initialize'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.2/lib/arjdbc/mysql/adapter.rb:396:in `initialize'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.2/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6:in `new'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.2/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6:in `jdbc_connection'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.2/lib/arjdbc/mysql/connection_methods.rb:18:in `mysql_connection'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
    classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
    /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/trainer-web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    classpath:/rack/adapter/rails.rb:36:in `serve_rails'
    classpath:/rack/adapter/rails.rb:41:in `call'
    classpath:/jruby/rack/rails.rb:180:in `call'
    classpath:/rack/handler/servlet.rb:19:in `call'
    <script>:2
|#]
```

it works perfectly fine under webrick on my local machine, but does this crap when i try to roll it out to a qa server. ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug due to unexpected Object.tap method behaviour, I created a [bug report](https://github.com/nicksieger/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/pull/72).

Comment: any ideas when this will make it into a release?